# OpenBTS-UMTS sim authentication failure

Tags: linux, authentication, sim, umts

I'm using OpenBTS-UMTS, and trying to authenticate a sim on the network ( sysmoSIM-SJS1-4FF ). 
The sim is successfully registered in sipauthserve with the following command (i used same syntax with IMSI and ki provided by my Sysmocom kit, the following is just an example):

```
./nmcli.py sipauthserve subscribers create "sim2" IMSI901712002174864 002 a74164d83db28ee2cdf2f043ae472044
```

Sucessful registration, this is what i get:

```
raw request: {"command":"subscribers","action":"create","fields":{"name":"sim2","imsi":"IMSI901712002174864","msisdn":"002","ki":"a74164d83db28ee2cdf2f043ae472044"}}
raw response: {
    "code" : 200,
    "data" : "both ok"
}
```

On mobile phone i search for networks and select TEST-PLMN-1 (default name of OpenBTS-UMTS network). I get the following error on OpenBTS-UMTS log:

> OpenBTS> ALERT 139647350089472 09:40:14.7 URRC.cpp:615:findUeByAsnId: no match ptmsi=0x0 raimatch=0 findHandlebyPTmsi-urnti=0x0
>
> 40:14.7 UL_CCCH_MessageType_PR_rrcConnectionRequest (new UE) UE#1 URNTI=466f stIdleMode rbid=0
>   newState: 1 1
>
> 40:14.7 DL_CCCH RRC_Connection_Setup_Message message size=58 UE#1 URNTI=466f stIdleMode rbid=0
>   newState: 2 1
>
> ALERT 139647350089472 09:40:15.5 URLC.cpp:1755:rlcWriteLowSide: stateChange: before 0 0 after 0 0
>
> 40:16.1 UL_DCCH_MessageType_PR_rrcConnectionSetupComplete UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH rbid=2
>
> 40:17.2 UL_DCCH_MessageType_PR_initialDirectTransfer UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH rbid=3
>
> 40:17.2 UL GMM Msg: AttachRequest UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH
>
> PDP of 0 is 0, gmm = f0004ab0, si = f0004820
>
> PDP of 5 is 0, gmm = f0004ab0, si = f0004820
>
> 40:17.2 DL_DCCH AuthenticationAndCipheringReq message size=25 UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH rbid=3
>
> PDP of 0 is 0
>
> 40:18.4 UL_DCCH_MessageType_PR_uplinkDirectTransfer UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH rbid=3
>
> 40:18.4 UL GMM Msg: AuthenticationAndCipheringFailure UE#1 URNTI=466f stCELL_FACH imsi=901712002174864

The sim should authenticate. Someone can help me in understanding what i'm missing?

Thank you